# Adding documentation in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I downloaded the jars of Apache POI Open Source project that supports manipulation of MS Office Files.

The folder that I downloaded contains a folder of javadocs of that project.

Now my query is that how can I integrate that with the netbeans so that the auto completion text box will show the docs of the functions of those jars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Tools|Libraries? There's a tab called Javadoc for each library, it might work

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on the project --> select properties --> Libraries (compile tab).
2. click on "Add JAR/Folder" and browse for "poi-3.9-20121203.jar" (included in "poi-bin-3.9-20121203.zip" and add it.
3. Afer adding it.. select it and click on "Edit". and add "poi-3.9-docs.jar" in Javadoc.

for detailed steps of step (3) --> see the guide in this link (first answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741449/apache-poi-sourcecode-javadoc