# How to extend java documentation in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I am using Netbeans 8.0.2 for java, while the auto-complete option is on and running it looks like not enough documentions is available or JavaDoc is missing, the message from Netbeans auto-complete says:

> Javadoc not found. Either Javadoc documentation for this item does not exist or you have not added specified Javadoc in the Java Platform Manager or the Library Manager.

When referring to Netbeans help on this everything seems in order.

So what is missing in Netbeans java documentation, or can it be extended?

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7766994/3651800?